# Flutter WebView Plugin Webpage goes blank

Tags: webview, flutter

I am using flutter Webview plugin which works fine but today i face a issue while displaying a webpage which contains only a image with 100% width and height. 
Therefore flutter Webview shows a blank page. When i change the height and width to a specific px for example 320px and 220px then only webview plugin shows the image otherwise with 100% the webpage goes blank.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin link to webview plugin

Comment: Please show your code

Answer (score 0):

You can try my plugin [flutter_inappbrowser](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappbrowser) (**EDIT**: it has been renamed to [flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview)).

An example loading an html source directly in the `InAppWebView` widget with an `img` with `width` and `height` to `100%`:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

Future main() async {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: InAppWebViewPage()
    );
  }
}

class InAppWebViewPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InAppWebViewPageState createState() => new _InAppWebViewPageState();
}

class _InAppWebViewPageState extends State<InAppWebViewPage> {
  InAppWebViewController webView;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("InAppWebView")
      ),
      body: Container(
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                child: InAppWebView(
                  initialData: InAppWebViewInitialData(
                    data: """
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <style>
            img {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="placeholder">
    </body>
</html>
                  """
                  ),
                  initialHeaders: {},
                  initialOptions: InAppWebViewWidgetOptions(
                      inAppWebViewOptions: InAppWebViewOptions(
                        debuggingEnabled: true,
                      )
                  ),
                  onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
                    webView = controller;
                  },
                  onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {

                  },
                  onLoadStop: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {

                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ]))
    );
  }
}
```